# I meet NullPointerException when I use Intent.getExtras

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

In method performCrop(), the code as following:

```
public void performCrop() {
    try {
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        ...
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        ...
    }
```

In method onActivityResult, the code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ...
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();//Here occurs the exception
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the parameter `data` is null, implying that the activity you started didn't return an `Intent` as a result. You should also check the `resultCode` because if this isn't RESULT_OK, the data returned is probably useless.

Comment: thx, but the problem disappears when I use android phone to test the program

Comment: So that means the emulator isn't doing the same thing as the phone.